# Hide rows based on the value of a specific cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("A1").Value = "Passed" Then
        Rows("2:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "Failed" Then
        Rows("2:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End If
End Sub
```

I am adding that to a regular VBA module. When I try to run it the system opens a macro screen. I want this to run in the background so everything I type Passed on A1 row 2 - 5 hides automatically.

I am using Excel 2012. Please help. Thanks :-)

Comment: Sorry. I am using Excel 2010

Answer (score 2):

Don't add it to a regular VBA module; put it in the module of the worksheet where you want this to happen.

[image]

The Worksheet_Change event will only fire if it's stored in the worksheet's code. I added this code to my object and it worked correctly, so just put it in your sheet and you should be good to go.

If you want it to run on multiple sheets, you have a couple of options. You can put the code as it is in each worksheet object, or you can put the code in a module and add a Call to each worksheet. Each sheet would have something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call PassFailCheck(Target)
End Sub
```

You can then put the bulk of your code in a module like this:

```
Sub PassFailCheck()
    If Range("A1").Value = "Passed" Then
        Rows("2:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "Failed" Then
        Rows("2:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The second option is a little more complex, but it's easier to maintain if you need to make changes to the code on a regular basis.